# conda command not found after installing Anaconda

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda, conda

I have Anaconda3 installed but when I open the terminal and type `conda` it said command not found and also the (base) environment does not appear in my terminal either (please see image). I have to do `source /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate` in order to use conda and see the (base) enviornment.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1ZU7.png) [As you can see, conda does not work at the first place and I have to activate it in order to make it work.]

Does anyone knows how to make conda work without doing `source /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate` at the first place?

I've tried setting auto_activate_base to be true using this command `conda config --set auto_activate_base true` but when I re-launch the terminal the issue still remain.
Also, I tried putting the following line into .bashrc: `export PATH="/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin"` and do `.source bashrc` and re-launch the terminal. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

for anaconda2/
$ export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH

for anaconda/
$ export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

and then
$ conda --version

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.